# Syncing a fork on github with Plastic SCM

Tags: github, plasticscm

I've been a great fan of Plastic SCM for a while now, using it locally for my own personal projects. Lately I've decided to contribute to an open source project on github. Since Plastic SCM can be used as a github client I decided to use it as such.

Now this is my first time using github, so I followed the classic github workflow as described in all the tutorials:

- Fork the repo to get your own copy
- Sync the Plastic SCM repo with the personal github repo
- Commit changesets in Plastic SCM
- Sync the Plastic SCM repo with github again

So far everything went fine. I contributed my code, uploaded it to github and saw all the changesets and branches appear in the github webui.

Next I put in a pull request to the original repo I forked from. This is where my problems start. The pull request was accepted, and a new changeset appeared in the original repo which contains my pull request. It seems all my intermediate branches did not transfer to the original repo either.

[image: github Network Graph]

As shown in the network graph above, the original repo (purple) is now no longer in sync with mine. I started with further development in another branch (VEH003) but this one seems to be completely disconnected from the original repo (purple).

In my Plastic SCM client I can see exactly the same network graphs in the branch explorer, with the exception of the purple branch.

I read that to update your fork with the changesets from the original repo this has to be done explicitly, and in your local git repository [(github help)](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork). Now I don't know how this is done using Plastic SCM.

Answer (score 2):

To sync your local fork with the original repo, as described in the github help, you need to merge the upstream master branch with your local master branch.

The point here is that Plastic SCM does not track or sync the upstream references (the references of the original repo), just your github's repo references.

To be able to update your fork, and continue working with Plastic SCM you should use the command line git client to perform the update following the guide you linked, push the local git changes to your github repository and then sync Plastic SCM with github to get the changes. Step by step:

- Use the git client to clone your github repository

  `git clone your-fork-url`
- Add the upstream repository.

  `git remote add upstream original-repo-url`
- Fetch the upstream references.

  `git fetch upstream`
- Merge upstream changes to your master branch.

  `git checkout master`

  `git merge upstream/master`
- Push master branch to your github repository.

  `git push origin master`
- Sync Plastic SCM with your github repo.